# How to convert blobUrl to MP3 in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to take an audio recording and throw it to firebase, I do this, but the file type goes to firebase incorrectly, when it goes correctly, I cannot listen to the audio in firebase.

```
 import {
  useReactMediaRecorder,
   } from "react-media-recorder";

  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, clearBlobUrl, mediaBlobUrl } =
useReactMediaRecorder({
  audio: true,
  blobPropertyBag: {
    type: "audio/m4a",
  },
});

const audioUpload = async (e: any) => {

      saveMedia(reader.result?.toString(), user);
```

};

Firebase :

```
const uploadImage = async (
  file: any,
  user: IUser
): Promise<IUploadImage | null> => {
  const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

  const child = "1abcd/koray-test/" + idGenerator();

  const imageRef = ref(storage, child);

  const snapshot = await uploadToFirebase(imageRef, file);

  if (!snapshot) {
    return null;
  }

  const fbReference = snapshot.ref.fullPath;

  return { fbReference, file };
};
```